# how to get radio button, checkbox value in csv using ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, csv, radio-button

I have a form field and a submit link. i'm generating csv through my php code. the code working fine but the main problem is i'm not able to get checked checkbox, radio button in csv. I'm using ajax and php.

Here is my html code

```
    <div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
        <div id="contact_results"></div>
        <div id="contact_body">

         <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" required="true" value="Male">
         <label for="male"><span></span>M</label>
         <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" required="true" value="Female">
         <label for="female"><span></span>F</label>
         <input type="radio" id="<18" name="age" required="true" value="<18">
         <label for="<18"><span></span><18</label>
         <input type="radio" id="18-25" name="age" required="true" value="18-25">
         <label for="18-25"><span></span>18-25</label>

         <input type="checkbox" id="men_fashion" name="Intrest" required="true" value="Men’s Fashion"/>
         <label for="men_fashion"><span></span>Men’s Fashion</label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="women_fashion" name="Intrest" required="true" value="Women’s Fashion"/>
        <label for="women_fashion"><span></span>Women’s Fashion</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="home_decor" name="Intrest" required="true" value="Home Decor"/>
        <label for="home_decor"><span></span>Home Decor</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gaming" name="Intrest" required="true" value="Gaming"/>
        <label for="gaming"><span></span>Gaming</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toys" name="Intrest" required="true" value="Toys"/>
        <label for="toys"><span></span>Toys</label>

        <a class="submit"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i></a>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here is jquery Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {        
        var proceed = true;  
        $("#contact_form input[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); 
                proceed = false; 
            }
        });

        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
            //get input field values data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'user_name'     : $('input[name=username]').val(), 
                'Gender'    : $('input[name=gender]').val(), 
                'Age'  : $('input[name=age]').val(), 
                'Intrest'  : $('input[name=Intrest').val(), 
                //'subject'       : $('select[name=subject]').val(), 
                //'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('post.php', post_data, function(response){  

            });
        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form  input[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
```

Here is my php code

```
<?php
 $cvsData = "";   //Initialize it as empty
if(isset($_POST['Intrest'])) {
    $name = $_POST['Intrest'];
    foreach ($name as $color){
        $cvsData .= $color. " ". " ";      //Append the new color value
    }
}
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
$Age = $_POST['Age'];


if(empty($fn) || empty($ln) || empty($phone)){
$message = 'Fill in areas in red!';
$aClass = 'errorClass';
}

$cvsData .= ",". $user_name. "," . $Age . "," .$Gender .",".  "\n"; //Append the second line here

//Add header here
$exists = true;
if (!is_readable("form.csv")) {
    $exists = false; 
}

$fp = fopen("form.csv","a");
if($fp){
   if (!$exists) { 
       fwrite("This is my awesome header\n"); 
   }
fwrite($fp,$cvsData); 
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Please help me out .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want the csv to actually contain a checkbox/radio, or you want a 1/0, a boolean, or the string value?

Comment: you need to change your code and take advantage of the `form` HTML element and jquery's `.submit()`.

Comment: whats the point of making all your `input name=Interest` required? do you want them all checked?

Comment: Hi @wrxsti actually i want checked checkbox string value. i can select multiple checkbox .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the `:checked` selector. Like so:

```
'Gender'    : $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(),
```

Comment: Hi @VoteyDisciple that's working fine for me thanks a lot . and i have have another problem how to i get multiple checkbox value ?

Answer (score 0):

I did changes in ajax

```
 'Gender'    : $('input[name=gender]:checked').val(),
 'Intrest':$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
                 return this.value
            }).get(),
```

And the rest of the code is same